# No data is being displayed in table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, angular-httpclient

I have created a simple test project to learn some Angular basics such as CRUD functions, `ngFor`, and `HttpClient` methods (get, post).

Now I have created a Firebase database with an API key and added some data so I can try to fetch it and display it in an HTML table using ngFor.

I have run into an issue where I believe my code is correct but I am not able to display any data on the screen and Chrome doesn't throw any error and neither does my compiler.

I got the data from the database using the `http.get` method and then mapped the object data to an array of objects using the pipe method built into Angular, once doing this I was able to subscribe to the data and attempted to use it in HTML table but nothing was displayed. I have attached my code files below, if someone could take a look and help me out that would be great.

Object class:

```
export class Courses {
  name: string;
  roomNumber: string;
  teacher: string;
  id?: string;
}
```

Course Component (course.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoursesService } from '../courses.service';
import { Courses } from '../courses';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  templateUrl: './courses.component.html'

})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
  courses;
  

  constructor(service: CoursesService) {
    this.courses = service.fetchCourses();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     
  }

}
```

Course service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Courses } from './courses';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoursesService {
  listofCourses: Courses[] = [];
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  fetchCourses() {
    return this.httpClient.get<{ [key: string]: Courses }>('https://testang-6c37f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/courses.json')
      .pipe(map((response) => {
        const courses = [];
        for (const key in response) {
          if (response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            courses.push({ ...response[key], id: key })
          }
        }
        return courses;
      }))
      .subscribe(courses => {
        console.log(courses)
        this.listofCourses = courses;
      });
  }
}
```

Course HTML:

```
<h2>Course List</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Room Number</th>
      <th>Teacher</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let course of listofCourses">
      <td>{{course.name}}</td>
      <td>{{course.roomNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{course.teacher}}</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

App module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
   CoursesService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

1.in the `Course service` remove the `.subscribe()` Return the value as Observable<Course[]>.
2.in the `Course component` Declare the courses as Observable<Course[]> type.
and in `ngOnInit` you have to subscibe to `fetchCourses` function

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
  this.courses = this.service.fetchCourses().subscribe({
next:(res)=>this.courses=res;
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Few issues with your current code.

1. You are creating the `courses` variable but didn't declare it with type. Declare the `courses` as `Observable<Course[]>` type.

```
courses: Observable<Course[]>;
```

2.1. Move the variable assigning into the `ngOnInit` lifecycle instead of with the constructor which is recommended.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.courses = this.service.fetchCourses();
}
```

2.2. The current code assigns the Subscription to the `courses` variable. Modify the `fetchCourses` method in `CoursesService`.

2.2.1. Remove the `.subscribe()`. Return the value as `Observable<Course[]>`.

```
fetchCourses() {
  return this.httpClient
    .get<{ [key: string]: Courses }>(
      'https://testang-6c37f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/courses.json'
    )
    .pipe(
      map((response) => {
        const courses = [];
        for (const key in response) {
          if (response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            courses.push({ ...response[key], id: key });
          }
        }
        return courses;
      })
    );
}
```

3. As we define `courses` as `Observable<Course[]>`, in the HTML use the `async` pipe to subscribe to the Observable.

```
<tr *ngFor="let course of courses | async">
    ...
</tr>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aemnjr?file=src/courses/courses.component.html)

Comment: Note that the attached demo uses standalone component, however if you read and understand the answer and code demo, you should able to implement the solution in non-standalone component.